# C - Header Files versus Functions

Tags: c, function, header

What are the pros and cons of shoving everything in one file:

```
void function(void) {
    code...
}
```

Versus creating a completely new file for functions:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "header.h"
```

Is one or the other faster? More lightweight? I am in a situation where speed is necessary and portability is a must.

Might I add this is all based on C.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you care about speed, you first should write a correct program, care about efficient algorithms (read [Introduction to Algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Introduction_to_Algorithms)), benchmark & [profile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Profiling_(computer_programming)) it (perhaps using [gprof](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/gprof/) and/or [oprofile](http://oprofile.sourceforge.net)), and focus your efforts mostly on the few percents of source code which are critical to performance.

You'll better *define* these small critical functions in common included header files as `static inline` functions. The compiler would then be able to [inline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inline_expansion) every call to them if it wants to (and it needs access to the *definition* of the function to inline).

In general small inlined functions would often run faster, because there is no call overhead in the compiled machine code; sometimes, it might perhaps go slightly slower, because inlining increases machine code size which is detrimental to [CPU cache](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPU_cache) efficiency (read about [locality of reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locality_of_reference)). Also a header file with many `static inline` functions needs more time to be compiled.

---

As a concrete example, my Linux system has a header `/usr/include/glib-2.0/glib/gstring.h` (from [Glib](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/) in GTK) containing

```
/* -- optimize g_string_append_c --- */
#ifdef G_CAN_INLINE
static inline GString*
g_string_append_c_inline (GString *gstring,
                          gchar    c)
{
  if (gstring->len + 1 < gstring->allocated_len)
    {
      gstring->str[gstring->len++] = c;
      gstring->str[gstring->len] = 0;
    }
  else
    g_string_insert_c (gstring, -1, c);
  return gstring;
}
#define g_string_append_c(gstr,c)       g_string_append_c_inline (gstr, c)
#endif /* G_CAN_INLINE */
```

The `G_CAN_INLINE` preprocessor flag would have been enabled by some previously included header file.

It is a good example of `inline` function: it is short (a dozen of lines), it would run quickly its own code (excluding the time to call to `g_string_insert_c`), so it is worth to be defined as `static inline`.

It is not worth defining as `inline` a short function which runs by itself a significant time. There is no point inlining a matrix multiplication for example (the call overhead is insignificant w.r.t. the time to make a 100x100 or 8x8 matrix multiplication). So choose carefully the functions you want to `inline`.

---

You should trust the compiler, and enable its [optimizations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimizing_compiler) (in particular when benchmarking or profiling). For [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/), that would mean compiling with `gcc -O3 -mcpu=native` (and I also recommend `-Wall -Wextra` to get useful warnings). You might use link time optimizations by compiling *and linking* with `gcc -flto -O3 -mcpu=native`

Answer (score 1):

You need to be clear about the concepts of header files, translation units and separate compilation.

The `#include` directive does nothing more than insert the content of the included file at the point of inclusion as if it were all *one file*, so in that sense placing content into a header file has no semantic or performance difference than *"shoving everything in one file"*.

The point is that is not how header files should be used or what they are intended for; you will quickly run into linker errors and/or code bloat on anything other than the most trivial programs.  A header file should generally contain *only* declarative code *not* definitive code.  Take a look inside the standard headers for example - you will find no function definitions, only declarations (there may be some interfaces defined as macros or possibly since C99, inline functions, but that is a different issue).

What header-files provide is a means to support separate compilation and linking of code in separate *translation units*.  A translation unit is a source file (.c in this case) with all it's `#include`'ed and `#define`'ed etc. content expanded by the pre-processor before actual compilation.

When the compiler builds a translation unit, there will be unresolved links to external code *declared* in headers.  These declarations are a promise to the compiler that there is an interface of the form declared that is defined elsewhere and will be resolved by the linker.

The conventional form (although there are few restrictions to stop you from dong unconventional or foolish things) of a multiple module C program source is as follows:

### main.c

```
#include foobar.h

int main( void )
{
    int x = foo() ;
    bar( x ) ;
    return 0 ;
}
```

---

### foobar.h

```
#if !defined foobar_INCLUDE
#define foobar_INCLUDE

int foo( void ) ;
void bar( int x ) ;

#endif
```

Note the use of the pre-processor here to prevent multiple declarations when a file is included more than once which can happen in complex code bases with nested includes for example.  All your headers should have such "include guards" - some compilers support `#pragma once` to do the same thing, but it is less portable.

---

### foobar.c

```
#include "foobar.h"

int foo( void )
{
    int x = 0 ;
    // do something
    return x ;
}

void bar( int x )
{
    // do something
}
```

---

Then main.c and foobar.c (and any other modules) are separately compiled and then linked, the linker also resolves references to library interfaces provided by the standard library or any other external libraries.  A *library* in this sense is simply a collection of previously *separately compiled* object code.

Now that is perhaps clear, to answer your question but re-present it as the pros and cons of *separate compilation and linking* the benefits are:

- code reuse - you build your own libraries of useful routines that can be reused in many projects without erroneous copy & pasting.
- Build time reduction - on a non-trivial application the separate compilation and linking would be managed by a build manager such as *make* or an IDE such as *Ecipse* or *Visual Studio*; these tools perform *incremental builds* compiling only those modules for which the source or one of it's header dependencies have been modified. This means you are not compiling all the code all the time so turn-around during debugging and testing is much faster.
- Development team scalability - if all your code is in one file, it becomes almost impractical to have multiple developers working on the same project at once.  If you want to work with others either on open-source projects or as a career (the two are not necessarily mutually exclusive of course), you really cannot consider the all-in-one approach.  Not least because your fellow developers will not take toy seriously if that is your practice.

Specifically separate compilation and linking has zero impact on performance or code size under normal circumstances.  There is possibly an impact on the ability of the compiler to optimise in some cases when it cannot see all of the code at one time, but if your code is carefully partitioned according to the principles of *high cohesion* and *minimal coupling* this potential loss of opportunity is probably insignificant.  Moreover modern linkers are able to perform some *cross-module* optimisations such as unused code removal in any case.

Answer (score -1):

Its not a question of which one is "faster". Header files are custom created when you have a function or functions which you'd want to use in a lot of other places or in other projects. For example, if you've written a function to calculate the factorial of a number and you'd want to use that function in other programs (or you find that you'd have to replicate the same code in other programs as well) then instead of writing the function in the other programs, it'll be more convenient if you'd put it in a header file. Generally, a header file contains functions which are relevant to a certain subject (like `math.h` contains functions for mathematical calculations and not for string processing).

Comment: But that does not answer the concern about efficiency.

Comment: ... or mention the fact that *functions* should not normally be defined in header files at all!

Comment: @Draco : Caution required - it may clear the question in your mind, but it will leave you seriously misinformed. You have accepted an answer that others feel strongly enough to comment on and even down-vote.  You might consider other answers before proceeding on the wrong path in your programming career.